# How can I find all members of an AD group and groups which are members of that group?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have an application-specific subtree of an AD domain accessed via LDAP.  In this subtree, I have a group which has as members a couple of groups outside my subtree (in a crowded, dense part of the whole tree).  There may be hundreds of users in the directory and I'm trying to identify a dozen or two.

I want to find all users who are members of my group.  Or alternatively, all groups which are members and the groups which may be members of those, etc. (which, I trust, is a small enough set that I could go back a second time and ask "give me the users who are members of this group or that group or the other group.")

I'm aware of `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` but it seems to only allow me to say "given group G, is user U a direct or indirect member of it?"  I can't figure out how to make that answer my question.

Let me try to illustrate:

```
ad-root/
├── corp
│   ├── sec-groups
│   │   ├── group-r
│   │   ├── group-s
│   │   └── group-t
│   └── users-ou
│       ├── user-a
│       ├── user-b
│       └── user-c
└── my-app
    ├── group-x
    ├── group-y
    └── group-z
```

Assume ad-root/corp/users-ou is quite large and sec-groups may be also.

- group r has members a, b, and c
- group s has members a and b
- group t has members b and c

Then, in my app's area

- group x has group s as its only member
- group y has groups r and s as members
- group z has groups x and y as members

I want to

- query group x and get users a and b
- query group y and get users a, b, and c
- query group z and get users a, b, and c

Alternatively, I want to

- query group x and get group s
- query group y and get groups r and s
- query group z and get groups r and s (I hoped `RULE_IN_CHAIN` would help here but I can't make it work.)

While not optimal, this would allow me to at least answer the question in exactly two queries:

1. What corporate security groups does my group resolve to?
2. What users are members of those groups? (E.g., `(|(memberOf=r)(memberOf=s))`)

Comment: Have you tried the other way around? Search for users that are member of a specific group. Start the search at the base of your domain and use a filter like `(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=cn=mygroup,dc=example,dc=com))`

Comment: The users are very definitely not members of the group, that's my problem.  I'll update the question to try to illustrate.